# Distribution of $\frac{X+ZY}{\sqrt{1 + Z^2}}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables with standard Gauss distribution. Let $Z$ be a random integer variable. All these variables are independent together.
I need to find distribution density of random variable $\frac{X+ZY}{\sqrt{1 + Z^2}}$

If I will use a fact $A$ that linear combination of normal distributions is a normal distribution with $\sigma = \sqrt{a^2\sigma_1^2 + b^2\sigma_2^2}$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + n^2}}X+\frac{n}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}Y$$
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+n^2}+\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}} = 1$$
then by using independence i could write it as $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\rho_1\mathbb{P}(Z=n)=\rho_1\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{P}(Z=n)=\rho_1$$ where $\rho_{\sigma}$ is density for normal distribution with constants $\sigma$ and $1$. But I don't know how to prove this linear combination fact $A$. So I would like know if my attempt is correct ($mod \:A$) and if  there are some other easier approaches or modifications of this one.

Comment: Do we assume $X,\,Y$ are independent?

Comment: @J.G. Yes. Maybe i should had written "mutually" independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any choice of $Z$, the marginal distribution is $N(0, \, 1)$. Therefore, the distribution is $N(0, \, 1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't answer my question if my solution is correct. And how do you get a fact that marginal distribution is N(0,1)? Right now it's almost what i had written.

Comment: @kb70145613 Your starting point is the right one, in that $A$ determines the on-$Z$ marginal distribution. (By the way, this discussion would be easier if you'd *named* $\tfrac{X+ZY}{\sqrt{1+Z^2}}$.)